# Why is it possible to call method on Java interface method? [Comparable]

Tags: java, interface, comparable

In AP Computer Science class today, I had this code:

```
    Comparable x = 45;
    Comparable y = 56;
    System.out.println(x.compareTo(y));
```

And this is valid. It prints 1 (or -1, I forget which), but it is possible to compare them.

I understand that interface variables refer to an object of a class that implements that interface, but what makes no sense to me is how an interface variable can be assigned an integer, and then have a method called on it. What object in this case is the compareTo() method being called on? Nothing was even instantiated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is called [*autoboxing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html), your primitive `int` type is automatically wrapped into an `Integer` instance, which is an object and it does implement `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 5):

Your integers are being boxed to Integers (i.e. `Objects`). That is to say, the primitives are being replaced by objects wrapping those primitives. Note that [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) implements `Comparable`.